# NodeJS : Dynamic import modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, import, node-modules

Is there any way in JS to import dynamically some modules ?

For example, this is my architecture :

```bash
| - index.js
| - modules
    | - SomeModule
        | - router.js
        | - controller.js
    | - SomeOtherModule
            | - SubModule
                | - router.js
                | - controller.js
        | - controller.js
```

My goal is to import all the `router.js` modules in the `index.js` file so I was thinking about something like this :

```js
import fs from "fs"
import path from "path"


function scanDirForRouters (dirPath, name = "") {
    let routers = []
    const files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath)
    for(const file of files) {
        const isDirectory = fs.statSync(path.join(dirPath, file)).isDirectory()
        if(isDirectory) {
            routers = [...routers, ...scanDirForRouters(path.join(dirPath, file), name + file)]
        }
        else if(file === "router.js") {
            routers.push(`import ${name}Router from ${path.join(dirPath, file)}`)
        }
    }
    return routers
}

let allRouters = scanDirForRouters(path.join(path.dirname("."), "modules"))
```

So if I do a console.log(allRouters) it gives me :

```js
[
  'import SomeModuleRouter from modules/SomeModule/Router.js',
  'import SomeOtherModuleSubModuleRouter from modules/SomeOtherModule/SubModule/Router.js'
]
```

So i wish there is a way to execute these command in my script now ... or maybe another way to do it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You could just use `require`...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @joprocoorp i found the answer using directly the import function in the loop.

This is my code :

```js
import fs from "fs"
import path from "path"


async function scanDirForRouters (dirPath, name = "") {
    let routers = []
    const files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath)
    for(const file of files) {
        const isDirectory = fs.statSync(path.join(dirPath, file)).isDirectory()
        if(isDirectory) {
            routers = [...routers, ...(async scanDirForRouters(path.join(dirPath, file), name + file))]
        }
        else if(file === "router.js") {
            const router = await import(`./${path.join(dirPath, file)}`)
            routers.push(router)
        }
    }
    return routers
}

let allRouters = await scanDirForRouters(path.join(path.dirname("."), "modules"))
```

then I can make a loop on the routers and do whatever i want :)

Answer (score 0):

Please, check eloader https://www.npmjs.com/package/eloader

It's load entire folders(recursive) or object instance.

```
const eloader = require('eloader');
const express = require('express');
 
let options = {debug: false};
 
eloader.addObject('options', options) //New methods
        .addServices('services')      //This will be loaded first.
        .addRoutes('routes')          //This third
        .run('loginRoute');       //This second
```

Comment: Thanks for the librairy, didn't know about it ! I'll check it soon :)

Answer (score -1):

You could use `require` instead. I implemented it by replacing the `routers.push` line :

```js
function scanDirForRouters (dirPath, name = "") {
    let routers = []
    const files = fs.readdirSync(dirPath)
    for(const file of files) {
        const isDirectory = fs.statSync(path.join(dirPath, file)).isDirectory()
        if(isDirectory) {
            routers = [...routers, ...scanDirForRouters(path.join(dirPath, file), name + file)]
        }
        else if(file === "router.js") {
            require(`${path.join(dirPath, file)}`)
        }
    }
    return routers
}

let allRouters = scanDirForRouters(path.join(path.dirname("."), "modules"))
```

Comment: I can't use "require" in a module environment ... I have to use import ... But, you gave me the solution ! :) Thanks